# How install django-auth-ldap==1.2.7 in Heroku servers?

Tags: python, django, heroku, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I'm trying to install this lib `django-auth-ldap==1.2.7` using `pip install` in **requirements.txt**.

I'm using **Heroku** services to deploy.

However, every time I try to **push/deploy** the code I can't quite finish the dependency check/install because pops this **error**:

> ```
> remote:        Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:18: fatal error: sasl.h: No such file or
> directory
> ```

I fallowed this question and answers: [python-ldap failed to install in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509607/python-ldap-failed-to-install-in-heroku)

But with **no luck**.

Basically, I've tried to use a third party **BUILDPACK**:

> ```
> heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/damgad/heroku-buildpack-python-ldap.git
> ```

And

> ```
> heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/damgad/heroku-buildpack-python-ldap.git
> ```

But still not working.

Can someone please,

1. Help me showing me a way to build my own **BUILDPACK** or
2. Pointing me an alternative solution?

Thanks!

---EDIT----

Just found out that a few *good* people are working to make it work.

There is a pull request trying to solve this problem of mine directly in heroku `default` **buildpack**.

> https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/pull/271

I will keep this question open and updated in case someone wonder the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you use a custom buildpack; all you've done is set an environment variable called BUILDPACK_URL.

Instead, follow the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack): you need `heroku buildpacks:set https://.....`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still not working... I can't install `django-auth-ldap`;  Can you help me ?